# SwiftUI view with warning for 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0 in safeAreaInsets

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

It creates crash and also generate warning in my code

My use of code :-
.offset(y: self.originTextField.y + UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.safeAreaInsets.top + 52)

Warning

```
'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes
```

Log

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28396b700 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x103fad930]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103facda0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28397c460 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x103fad930.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x28232e680'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28397c4b0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x103facda0]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x28232e4c0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283969f40 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x28232e4c0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x103fabfd0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2839799a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x103fabfd0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28396a300 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x28232e680'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x103fabfd0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28396b700 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x103fad930]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103facda0 )>
```

Answer (score 1):

As iOS 13 comes with multi-scene support, you need to rely on `connectedScenes` to retrieve the active window. You can use the following extension to get the active window and then can access `safeAreaInsets` from that window.

```swift
// MARK: - UIApplication+Extension
extension UIApplication {
    var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        return UIApplication.shared
            .connectedScenes
            .first(where: { $0 is UIWindowScene })
            .flatMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }?.windows
            .first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
    }
}

// MARK: - Usage
.offset(y: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0)
```

Comment: Its not working